Matplotlib table blitting
I have a figure with multiple axes and a table, all using blitting to display data in real-time. The axes work just fine however the table doesn't show up with animated=True. If I set animated=False it shows the data values at the time the program starts but doesn't update as the data changes with time.
In update_plot I've tried adding the three lines below the table set_text(~), each independently and none work with animated=True. There are also two other artists, a map and a buttonPatch which I've left out.
Here's the relevant lines from the program:
# Set up GUI elements

# Right hand side time-graphs

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5) = plt.subplots(5, sharex=True, figsize=[10,10], animated=True) # animated=True tells matplotlib to only draw the artist (axes) when we explicitly tell it (in FuncAnimation)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle()
plt.xticks(\[\])

fig.suptitle('Telemetry, Car #770')
ax1.set_ylabel('RPM  ', rotation='horizontal', horizontalalignment='right')
ax2.set_ylabel('TPS \[%\] ', rotation='horizontal', horizontalalignment='right')
ax3.set_ylabel('Air-Fuel Ratio ', rotation='horizontal', horizontalalignment='right')
ax4.set_ylabel('Water Temp \[°F\] ', rotation='horizontal', horizontalalignment='right')
ax5.set_ylabel('MAP \[psi\]  ', rotation='horizontal', horizontalalignment='right')

ax1.set_xlim(\[listLength-1, 0\]) # Time axis
ax1.set_ylim(\[0,7300\]) # RPM
ax2.set_ylim(\[0,100\]) # TPS
ax3.set_ylim(\[0,25\]) # AFR
ax4.set_ylim(\[0,250\]) # Water temp
ax5.set_ylim(\[0,20\]) # Manifold Air Pressure (absolute, psi)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle()

line1, = ax1.plot(xlist, zerolist, 'r-')
line2, = ax2.plot(xlist, zerolist, 'r-')
line3, = ax3.plot(xlist, zerolist, 'r-')
line4, = ax4.plot(xlist, zerolist, 'r-')
line5, = ax5.plot(xlist, zerolist, 'r-')

# Bottom left table

table = plt.table(cellColours=\['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'\], cellLoc='right', rowLabels=\['RPM', 'TPS', 'Fuel Burned \[gal\]', 'AFR', 'Water Temp \[°F\]', 'MAP \[psi\]', 'Voltage'\], loc='left', bbox=\[-0.7,0.1, 0.15, 2.5\], animated=True)
#ax1.add_table(table)
table.set_fontsize(20)

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, left=0.5, right=0.98, top=0.92, bottom=0.05)
plt.pause(0.1)

# draw the animated artist (the figure)

fig.draw_artist(ax1)
fig.draw_artist(ax2)
fig.draw_artist(ax3)
fig.draw_artist(ax4)
fig.draw_artist(ax5)
fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox) # show the result to the screen

class Visualization:
def __init__(self):
self.ACKflag = 0

    def update_plot(event, self):
    
        # Put new data in each of the line artist objects
        line1.set_ydata(dataObject.RPMlist)
        line2.set_ydata(dataObject.TPSlist)
        line3.set_ydata(dataObject.AFRlist)
        line4.set_ydata(dataObject.WaterTemplist)
        line5.set_ydata(dataObject.MAPlist)
        #line5.set_ydata(dataObject.steerPoslist)
    
        # Put new data in each of the table cells
        table[(0,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.RPM)
        table[(1,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.TPS)
        table[(2,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.total)
        table[(3,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.AFR)
        table[(4,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.WaterTemp)
        table[(5,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.MAP)
       # table[(6,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.dutyCycle)
        table[(6,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.voltage)
       # table[(8,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.ignitionAngle)
       # table[(9,0)].get_text().set_text(dataObject.revolutions)
    
        #table.draw_artist(table) # try this to see if the table works
        #table.draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer()) # try this to see if the table works
        #self.canvas.flush_events()
    
    
        return line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, map, buttonPatch, buttonLabel

# Create an instance of the Visualization class, and pass it to the animation loop

vis = Visualization()
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, vis.update_plot, interval=dataPeriod, save_count=listLength, blit=True)
plt.show()


Welcome to stackoverflow! To easier be able to identify the issue, please provide a [mre]. Your code cannot not be run directly (dataObject is not defined, etc...), and contains many elements which are not connected to your issue with the table. Try breaking it down to a few lines of code to directly reproduce the issue.
